# How would I convert a txt file containing a lot of symbols into a array?

Tags: codeigniter

so I just have a quick question. The program is supposed to create a character array, and get the content from a text file, containing a lot of random symbols like &,?,!,letters, and numbers. I am not allowed to create seperate arrays, and put them into the 2d array instead. How would I go about doing so? I already know the number of rows and columns because it tells me at the top of the file before actually having all the symbols and stuff. Heres what I have so far:

```
    char [][]charArray=new char[a][b];
    for(int z=0;z<charArray.length;z++)
    {
        for(int y=0;y<charArray[y].length;y++)
        {
            charArray[y]=fileReader.next();

        }
    }
```

So A is the number of rows, and B is the number of columns to read from. When I run the program, it says that it is expecting a char []charArray, and it found a string, and the error is called an incompatible type error.
ALso ps: fileReader is my scanner to read from a file. THanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to use more descriptive names for your variables. For example, why name the variable `a` when `a` really represents the number of rows in the file? Instead, use `numRows` (and likewise for `b`, use `numCols`). Also, you really should name your scanner `scanner`. There is a `FileReader` class and your `fileReader` variable name is misleading---it makes everyone think you're using a `FileReader` instead of a `Scanner`. Finally, the brackets used to declare an array type in Java are normally placed adjacent to the type name, as in `char[][]` instead of `char [][]`. This does not change the way the code executes, but it conforms better to common convention.

Now, to your problem. You stated that the number of rows/columns are declared at the beginning of the file. This solution assumes the file does in fact contain `numRows` rows and `numCols` columns. Basically, `next` returns a `String`. You can use `String.toCharArray` to convert the `String` to a `char[]`. Then you simply copy the characters to the appropriate position in your `charArray`.

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(theFile);

    char[][] charArray=new char[numRows][numCols];

    for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {

        final char[] aLine = scanner.next().toCharArray();
        for(int j = 0; j < aLine.length;j++){
            charArray[i][j] = aLine[j];
        }

    }
```